# C++ memory allocation in arrays

Tags: c++, memory

```
    int m,n;
    cin>>m>>n;
    int A[m][n];
```

Question is: Will array A get memory on stack or heap in C++ ?

Edit: I know using new is a better route. 
This technique works in my mingw g++ compiler. I am just curious.

Comment: Technically it should be a compiler error.

Comment: But it works. So in that case ?

Comment: @DeepankarArya Doesn't work in Visual Studio, any version.

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour depends on the particular compiler and is **not part of the standard**.

In `gcc`, which `mingw` is a port of, the memory for `automatic variables` as such, including `variable lengths arrays` is allocated on the stack.

According to the `gcc` manual:

> **6.19 Arrays of Variable Length**
>
> [...] These arrays are declared like any other automatic arrays, but with a
>   length that is not a constant expression. The storage is allocated at
>   the point of declaration and deallocated when the block scope
>   containing the declaration exits. [...] You can use the function **alloca** to get an effect much like variable-length arrays.

*Ref:* https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

According to `man 3 alloca`:

> The  space  allocated by alloca() is allocated within the stack frame

Please keep in mind that:

> ISO C++ **forbids** variable length arrays

Alternatively you can allocate your array dynamically (with `new`) or preferably use the C++ containers anyway where possible.

---

*Edit: Added note on variable behaviour between compilers, based on Paul's comment.*

Comment: Works for me in mingw g++

Comment: @DeepankarArya "Works" because of a g++ extension. It is non-standard, and a year from now may not be supported.

Comment: Even in that case, where is the memory coming from stack or heap ?

Comment: I think you need "-pedantic" to get such a warning.

Comment: @FredLarson: Ok, without  `-Wall` I get no warning at all

Comment: @DeepankarArya Most likely on the stack.

Comment: @vsoftco I suspect it to be heap. Stack elements should be of known size at compile time right ?

Comment: @DeepankarArya That memory is placed wherever your compiler's non-standard behavior decides to place it. You want to find out -- generate the assembly language.